# Codeigniter - db->get() not returning same result as same query with PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I am having a problem with Codeigniter where the result I get from the db->get() is not the same as the same query issued to the database via PHPMyAdmin. The results are the same except for the id field which is not.

The Listings MySQL table is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `listings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` tinytext NOT NULL COMMENT 'Name of listing',
  `type` set('Bar','Bar and Restaurant','Cinema','Club','Concert','Dance activity','Dance performance','Demonstration/protest','Event','Exercise','Exhibition','Gallery','Lecture','Opera','Other','Market','Museum','Park','Protest','Pub','Physical activity','Restaurant','Sight seeing','Sport','Street food','Take away','Theatre','Tourist attraction','Transport','Walks') NOT NULL COMMENT 'Type of listing',
  `price` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Price of listing',
  `shortDescription` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `longDescription` text NOT NULL,
  `website` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `phoneNumber` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `address` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `image1` varchar(60) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Filename of 1st image',
  `image2` varchar(60) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Filename of 2nd image',
  `image3` varchar(60) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Filename of 3rd image',
  `days` set('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday','Monday to Friday','Monday to Saturday','Monday to Sunday') NOT NULL COMMENT 'Days of week this listing is open',
  `openingTimes` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'Text description of opening times in specific format',
  `validFrom` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'Date this listing is active from',
  `validTo` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'Date this listing is availably until',
  `bookmarked` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Number of times this has been bookmarked',
  `dateAdded` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'date this listing was added',
  `dateLastAmended` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'date this listing was last changed',
  `latitude` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `longitude` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `publish` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'If set listing is published and available to show',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Data for each listing' AUTO_INCREMENT=877 ;
```

The listings_categories MySQL table is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `listings_categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `listingId` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Associated listing',
  `arts` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `entertainment` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `events` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `food` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `nightlife` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `outdoor` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=553 ;
```

The query being run is:

```
SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(51.24977493163702) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-2.8468933105468737) ) + sin( radians(51.24977493163702) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) 
AS distance FROM listings JOIN listings_categories 
ON listings_categories.listingId = listings.id 
WHERE listings.price <= 40 
AND ( listings_categories.arts = 1 
OR listings_categories.entertainment = 1 
OR listings_categories.events = 1 
OR listings_categories.food = 1 
OR listings_categories.nightlife = 1 
OR listings_categories.outdoor = 1) 
HAVING distance < 1000 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 100;
```

The first of the results returned by PHPMyAdmin and exported as a PHP array is:

```
$listings = array(
  array(
'id'=>485,
'name'=>'Layla Restaurant',
'type'=>'Bar,Bar and Restaurant,Restaurant',
'price'=>22,
'shortDescription'=>'Lebanese',
'longDescription'=>'<p>
 Layla Restaurant is a stylish Lebanese restaurant in Esher. Settle down on cushions and enjoy a meal of traditional Lebanese food and meze. Or &nbsp;relax in the lounge and enjoy cocktails and belly dancing that Layla restaurant provides.</p>
',
'website'=>'http://www.laylarestaurant.co.uk/',
'phoneNumber'=>02089447696,
'address'=>'33 High Street Esher Kingston',
'postcode'=>'KT10 9QL',
'image1'=>'5f1ad-layla_fotor.jpg',
'image2'=>'7869f-layla2_fotor.jpg',
'image3'=>'',
'days'=>'Monday to Sunday',
'openingTimes'=>'Mon-Thu 12:00-00:00
Fri-Sat 12:00-01:30
Sun 12:00-23:00',
'validFrom'=>'0000-00-00',
'validTo'=>'0000-00-00',
'bookmarked'=>0,
'dateAdded'=>'2014-11-01',
'dateLastAmended'=>'2014-11-01',
'latitude'=>51.368423,
'longitude'=>-0.367311,
'publish'=>1,
'id'=>464,
'listingId'=>485,
'arts'=>0,
'entertainment'=>0,
'events'=>0,
'food'=>1,
'nightlife'=>1,
'outdoor'=>0,
'distance'=>107.41168679083839)
);
```

The first of the results returned by db->get() in Codeigniter is:

```
["id"]=> string(3) "464" 
["name"]=> string(16) "Layla Restaurant" 
["type"]=> string(33) "Bar,Bar and Restaurant,Restaurant" 
["price"]=> string(2) "22" 
["shortDescription"]=> string(8) "Lebanese"
...
```

I can see that the problem is due to me having two id fields in the result. One from the listings table and one from the listings_categories table and that I am picking up the wrong one when using the results from the db->get().

So my question is how can I make sure I pick up the correct id?

The code I currently use is:

```
    foreach ($queryResult->result() as $row)
    {
        $data["results"][$i]["name"] = $row->name;
        $data["results"][$i]["id"] = $row->id;
        $data["results"][$i]["distance"] = $row->distance;
        $data["results"][$i]["shortDescription"] = $row->shortDescription;
        $data["results"][$i]["image1"] = $row->image1;
        $data["results"][$i]["price"] = $row->price;
        $i++;
    }
```

Comment: The results in your question are incomplete. I miss the `distance` in the result. How can I trust your question?

Comment: Apologies for foolishly trying to keep the question brief and so leave out essential information! You were right to insist on full details and by providing this I can now see where the problem lies. My database query is returning two 'id' fields (one from each of the two joined tables) and I am picking up the wrong one. So my question should have been how to access  the correct id in the results.

Comment: Ah, yes, that was one of the possible errors I was thinking of. Anyway, it's solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `var_dump($row)` in the `for_each()` loop you have and check the fields obtained, it might have so happened that the id field have been overwritten(which I guess probably the case is) or the tablename have been appended to the other `id` field`.

`foreach ($queryResult->result() as $row)
     { 
        var_dump($row);
        die();
     }` to see the fields

And as a better programming practice whenever there are similar field names across different its always good to have the field name as `tablename_fieldname`, so in your case the field names should be `listings_categories_id` and `listings_id`